# How to compile procedure in postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

Is there any alternative in postgres to compile procedure as oracle? I searched ,but couldn't find any relevant alternatives for it . Can anyone suggest on this?

alter procedure proc_name compile. in oracle

equivalent to postgres.

Comment: There is no such thing in Postgres. What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: Procedures written in C must be compiled, but outside of PostgreSQL and loaded afterwards. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-c.html#DFUNC

Answer (score 5):

User-defined functions are *interpreted* in PostgreSQL, so there is no need to compile them. The function code is stored as a string, and a *procedural language handler* executes it when the function is called. This may of course lead to some kind of on-the-fly compilation process, but this is dependent on the procedural language being used.

PL/pgSQL does not compile anything (but it caches the plans of static SQL statements executed in the function).